# "Remote host closed connection during handshake" when connecting to FTP server using Commons Net FTPSClient

Tags: java, ssl, ftp, apache-commons-net

My **code** (I use `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` VM argument when run):

```
FTPSClient ftpClient = new FTPSClient("TLS", false);
ftpClient.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
ftpClient.setAuthValue("TLS");

ftpClient.connect("myhost", 990);
ftpClient.login("mylogin", "mypassword");
```

Stack trace:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection
>   during handshake
>         at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:992)
>       // too many traces...
>       Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
>         at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
>         at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
>         ... 33 more

Log from WinSCP (I can send files using WinSCP):

> 536 Copying 1 files/directories to remote directory "/" 536   PrTime:
>   Yes; PrRO: No; Rght: rw-r--r--; PrR: No (No); FnCs: N; RIC: 0100;
>   Resume: S (102400); CalcS: Yes; Mask: *.* 536   TM: B; ClAr: No;
>   RemEOF: No; RemBOM: No; CPS: 0; NewerOnly: No; InclM: ; ResumeL: 0 536
>   AscM: *.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; *.cgi; *.c; *.cpp; *.h;
>   *.pas; *.bas; *.tex; *.pl; *.js; .htaccess; *.xtml; *.css; *.cfg; *.ini; *.sh; *.xml 539 File: 'C:\Users\trescon.jramos\Documents\cliente-dados.sql'
>   [2016-10-06T16:34:29.298Z] [4869] 557 Copying
>   "C:\Users\trescon.jramos\Documents\cliente-dados.sql" to remote
>   directory started. 560 Binary transfer mode selected. 560 Iniciando
>   carregamento de C:\Users\trescon.jramos\Documents\cliente-dados.sql
>   560 TYPE I 562 200 Type set to I 563 PASV 568 227 Entering Passive
>   Mode (10,28,14,218,250,0) 569 STOR cliente-dados.sql 569 Conectando a
>   10.28.14.218:64000... 575 150 Opening data channel for file upload to server of "/cliente-dados.sql" 579 Session ID reused 579 Using
>   TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit
>   RSA, ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA 
>   Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD 580 Conexão SSL estabelecida 586 226
>   Successfully transferred "/cliente-dados.sql" 586 MFMT 20161006163429
>   cliente-dados.sql 590 213 modify=20161006163429; /cliente-dados.sql
>   590 Carregamento bem-sucedido 591 Transfer done:
>   'C:\Users\trescon.jramos\Documents\cliente-dados.sql' [4869]

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting to port 990, what is an implicit FTPS port. Yet, you are passing `false` to `isImplicit` argument of [`FTPSClient` constructor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPSClient.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,boolean)).

Either pass `true`, if you really want to use the implicit FTPS:

```
FTPSClient ftpClient = new FTPSClient("TLS", true);
```

Or actually, you should really use an explicit FTPS and the default FTP port 21 (as the implicit FTPS is non-standard legacy compatibility hack):

```
FTPSClient ftpClient = new FTPSClient();
// ...
ftpClient.connect("myhost");
```

In other words, all you need to use FTPS is use [`FTPSClient`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPSClient.html), no additional arguments or calls are needed.